# How to read from files which has tfrec extension in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am a beginner in TensorFlow and I have a difficult time understanding how to read tfrec extension files which stores images, I read the documentation but it is very confusing, can you help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you add a code sample which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
files = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(filenames)
dataset = files.apply(tf.contrib.data.parallel_interleave(tf.data.TFRecordDataset,
                                                          cycle_length=argument.num_parallel_readers, sloppy=True))
dataset = dataset.map(input_parse_exmp, num_parallel_calls=16)
# Shuffle, repeat, and batch the examples.
dataset = dataset.batch(argument.batch_size)
```